# Como continuar el llenado de una matriz despues de un Try Catch

Tags: java, matriz, try-catch

La matriz solo admite valores enteros. Al momento de ingresar algún caracter o string entra  al catch y termina por completo el ciclo. Pero después del mensaje del catch quiero seguir con el llenado de la matriz en la posición en la que se quedó pero me manda al punto de inicio. Como puedo resolverlo?... Help, por fis :(

```
public static final int FILAS = 3;
public static final int COLUMNAS = 4;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static int i,j;
static int[][] m = new int [FILAS][COLUMNAS];


public static void read(){
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {//x
            for (j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {//y
                m[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("[" + i + "][" + j + "]= ");
            }
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nError...Debe ingresar unicamente valores enteros ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, puedes ir guardando tanto la variables `i` como la `j` en otras variables que le hagan referencia y cuando vuelvas a iniciar los bucles tomas como dato a las variables creadas, ya no al `i` ni al `j`

Answer (score 1):

El `try... catch` sobre todo el ciclo no tiene sentido. Solo debes colocar dentro del `try...catch` lo que en realidad podría dar error, en este caso, la lectura y parseado del número dentro de la consola.

La idea es la siguiente, para cada número que quieras leer, comienza inicializando una variable que indique la validez del dato a `false`. Luego envuelve toda la asignación en un `while`, de manera que hasta que el dato que te pasen no sea válido, no vas a dejar al usuario salir del ciclo. Con eso, ya tienes tu problema resuelto.

Nota que he cambiado el `nextInt` por `Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine() );` ya que `nextInt` suele traer bastantes problemas al no consumir los saltos de línea.

```
public static void read() {
    for (i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {//x
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {//y
            boolean isValid = false;
            while (!isValid) {
                try {
                    System.out.print( "[" + i + "][" + j + "]= " );
                    m[i][j] = Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine() );
                    isValid = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println( "\nError...Debe ingresar unicamente valores enteros " );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por ayudarme y mostrarme esos errores, de verdad lo agradezco !!

Answer (score 1):

Mueve el `try/catch` para que solo cubra la parte del código que puede producir la excepción. Luego en el `catch` puedes decrementar la variable `j` y usar `continue` para volver a repetir esa iteración.

```
public static void read() {
    for (i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {//x
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {//y
            try {
                m[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\nError...Debe ingresar unicamente valores enteros ");
                // retroceder el valor de j para que vuelva a pedir
                // el dato en esta posición
                j--;
                // pasar a la siguiente iteraci´øn
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print("[" + i + "][" + j + "]= ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesante solución +1, al principio me quedé un poco asustado, porque es que `j--` da `-1` si `j=0`, pero es que luego se incrementa de nuevo y vuelve a su valor al entrar al ciclo y por ello funciona perfecto. Nunca se me hubiera ocurrido.

Comment: ohh valee entiendo. Muchas gracias de verdad !!!